# Showing the existence of a right-inverse in a von Neumann probability space

Tags: pr.probability, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Disclaimer: This is my first post here on Overflow as opposed to the "normal" forum, so if this question is too elementary for this forum, I'd appreciate y'all letting me know. I posted it [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4050981/showing-the-existence-of-a-right-inverse-in-a-von-neumann-algebra), and didn't get a response yet, so I thought I'd post it here in case it was a better fit.

In [this paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01886871.pdf), specifically Theorem 4.1 on page 10, one of the last steps in the proof involves saying that a particular right-inverse exists. I'll try to restate what I think are the relevant pieces of info here, instead of just rewriting the whole proof.

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a von Neuman algebra with a faithful normal state $\rho$. In the last paragraph, the author looks at a self-adjoint, positive element $y \in \mathfrak{A}$, and then defines $q = \chi_{(1/2, 1]}(y)$, where this latter expression is meant in the sense of the Borel functional calculus on a self-adjoint $y \in \mathfrak{A}$. This $q$ satisfies
$$q \leq 2y \leq q + 1 \; (\dagger).$$
He then claims that there must exist $z \in \mathfrak{A}$ such that $\| z \|\leq 2$ and
$$1 - q = (1- y) z \; (\dagger \dagger) .$$

I'm confused at two steps. First, at $(\dagger)$, I'm a little confused about how he gets these two inequalities. I understand how to handle the inequality in the "commutative" (i.e. measure-theoretic) context by looking at how $\chi_{(1/2, 1]} \circ y_m$ would act on a point in the domain of the *function* $y_m$. I assume that my basic intuitions about measure theory can be carried over into this setting via the Borel functional calculus, but I'd like to understand how to make this reasoning rigorous.

Second, I don't understand how the author infers the existence of $z$ in $(\dagger \dagger)$, or the norm estimate on $z$.

If anyone here can clear up either of my questions, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Suggestion: you can confine attention to the von Neumann algebra generated by $y$.  This is commutative and so representable as an $L^\infty$-algebra. You can apply your line of thought there.

Comment: There is also now a pretty good answer given to the math.SE version of the question.  It's often worth waiting a day or more on math.SE